# python) curve fitting (parameter estimation)

Tags: python, parameters, estimation

i'm trying to do parameter estimation using python but there are some troubles.

whenever i change initial values or bounds, the values of parameters are changed.

i know that initial values and bounds affect the parameter values but The fluctuations are too large.

And the difference between the predicted values and true values is also too large.

Could you tell me what i shoud do?

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


E= np.array([(3.652,3.604,3.53,3.47,3.373,3.265,3.205,3.128,3.022,2.957,2.881,2.8,2.707,2.661,2.586,2.494),(0.728,0.727,0.725,0.724,0.722,0.719,0.718,0.717,0.715,0.714,0.712,0.711,0.709,0.708,0.707,0.706),(0.0029375,0.002895295,0.002851811,0.002809605,0.0027674,0.002723916,0.002681711,0.002639505,0.002596021,0.002553816,0.002511611,0.002468126,0.002425921,0.002383716,0.002340232,0.002298026)])

def func(E,a,b):
    return (a*b*E[0,:]*E[1,:])/((1+b*E[1,:])**2)

guess= ([0.005,5])
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, E[:2,:], E[2,:], guess, bounds=(0,[100,100]), maxfev=10000)

print(popt)
print(pcov)

#true values = [a : 0.0055 ± 0.00055, b : 5.52 ± 0.57]
#predicted values = [ a : 6.2364958e-02, b:1.0000000e+02]
```

Comment: What are your intended bounds for a and b, respectively?

Comment: I think it's mostly your data that is not defining enough: it can be anywhere on the slope of your function, but since it's missing the actual peak in the data, it can't determine the precise values.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. actually i wanna make a new reaction rate equation so to get precise values of parameters, i'm trying practicing parameter estimation using the function that is taken from a paper.

Comment: In the paper, there are data and parameter values so i can get parameter values within the margin of error changing initial values and bounds.
But in my new reaction rate function, whenever i change initial values and bounds, the parameter values will be changed.

Comment: however, i don't know the precise parameter values so i can't determine what parameter values are correct. Is it possible that i can get exact parameter values withing large bounds?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is look at your covariance matrix. Provided the off-diagonal elements are not too large, the square root of the diagonal elements are a good estimate of the errors of your fitted parameters. See how precise these are. If they are large, and much larger than the values you have from the paper (the given "true values"), then either the author papers had more data or other information, or they did a bad job.

Comment: Also, if the errors are large, then that is simply the precision you can get from your fit. As I mentioned before: then your data, compared to your current model, is just too limited for an accurate fit.

Comment: In the limited bounds( 0<a<1, 0<b<7), i can get the parameter values within the margin of error and the covariance matrix is [(7.439e-05,1.327e-1), (1.327e-1,,2.367e+2)].

Comment: I should find whether there is any information that i don't know in the paper. thanks a lot!

Comment: As you can see, for b between 0 and 7, its error is about 15 (so its 1-sigma error is already outside of its bounds). I guess if let the bounds for b be larger, its error will also be larger. To me, that indicates your problem is indeed rather ill-constrained.

Comment: Does it work to change the method from curve_fitting to least_squares to reduce the error?

Comment: No: `curve_fitting` just wraps around `least_squares`, with an easier interface. The error problem is intrinsic to your data, as far as I can tell.